# Add children Route's in a component React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am trying to add `<route>` in a component inside a routers component, but didn't work. Please, someone can help me? My login page, have a form and I want to just change the form with routes.

I'm using `react-router-dom` v5.

```
-<Login />
--<LoginForm/>
---<Default/>
---<DadosPessoais/>
```

Routes.js

```
 <Router>  
 <Route path="/login" exact component={Login}/>
</Router>
```

Login.js

```
 <div id="login-main">
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row" id="login-content" className={ForgotPassWordState ? "forgot" : ""}>
                    <div>
                        <LoginForm/>
                    </div>
                    <BannerAdvogados />
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
```

LoginForm.js

```
<div id="login-form">
            <div id="login-logo">
                <img src={logo} alt="Page logo"/>
            </div>
         
                    <div className="title-form">
                        <h2>Bem-vindo de volta a Page!</h2>
                        <p>Preencha os campos abaixo e acesse sua conta</p>  
                    </div>
                    
                        <Route path="/login" exact component={Default} />
                        <Route path="/login/dados" exact component={DadosPessoais} />  
                </>

            }
        </div>
```

Comment: you need to wrap the route in `Routes.js` with a switch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First issue is that the root route is only rendered when it ***exactly*** matches `"/login"`, so if the URL/path becomes `"/login/dados"` it no longer matches exactly and `Login` is unmounted.

Remove the `exact` prop on the root `Route` component so subroutes/nested routes can be matched and rendered.

Login.js

```
<Router>  
  <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
</Router>
```

Second issue, the `Router` ***inclusively*** (*means anything that matches is rendered*) matches and renders routes, this is likely why you are trying to use the `exact` prop on all the nested routes. Use a `Switch` component to ***exclusively*** (*only the **first** match is rendered*) a route. While you *could* continue using the `exact` prop on all nested routes, it's simpler to render them into a `Switch` in descending order of path specificity (*i.e. more specific paths before less specific paths*).

LoginForm.js

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/login/dados" component={DadosPessoais} /> 
  <Route path="/login" component={Default} />
</Switch>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you use `react-router-dom` v5?

When you use the newest version you have to add

```js
<BrowserRouter>
```

Around your complete "App"

Inside it you define

```js
<Routes>
   <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
   <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
</Routes>
```

Comment: Becuase this project it was already complete. To change to version 6, it will be necessary to change all application routes.